# golangci-lint error go imports error computing diff

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I´m trying to use golangci-lint with vscode, however when i run it, the following error occurs

> level=warning msg="[runner] Can't run linter goanalysis_metalinter: goimports: error computing diff: exec: "diff": executable file not found in %PATH%"
> level=error msg="Running error: 1 error occurred:\n\t* can't run linter goanalysis_metalinter: goimports: error computing diff: exec: "diff": executable file not found in %PATH%\n\n"

Does anyone know what do do?

Comment: What is the output for `which diff`

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi i´m on windows, says the command is not recognized

Comment: Ah your question dosent mention you are on windows. Anyways looks like you are missing a diff tool. Install one from https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm and restart your machine and try the go command again. Also make sure the diff tool you add is there in your path

Comment: @SuyashMedhavi added C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\diff3.exe to path, still not working, any ideas? Thanks for your help

Comment: I believe its looking for an exe named `diff` and not `diff3`. See you can fix that. Worst case, rename the exe